# How to find largest number in file and see on which line it is

Tags: python

The file looks like this:

```
1, a b
2, c d
3, e f
```

my current code

```
b = open('file.txt', 'r')

c = b.readlines()
regels = len(c)

print(regels)
```

I got the numbers of lines but still need biggest number + on which line it is.

Comment: so the first column is the line number, next two are numbers?  and you just want to find the biggest single number in file returning line number?

Comment: @MooingRawr that is correct. Finding the biggest number and telling what line it is on.

Answer (score 1):

So you are just looking to find the biggest number in the first column of the file? This should help

```
b = open('file.txt', 'r')

c = b.readlines()
regels = len(c)

print(regels)

max = 0
for line in b.readlines():
  num = int(line.split(",")[0])
  if (max < num):
    max = num 


print(max)
# Close file
b.close()
```

Comment: Well won't it read the data as a string? In which case, once you get past line 9, `num = int(line[0])` wouldn't work?

Comment: You forgot to close your file.

Comment: thanks @reticentroot and I think the for loop should work for all the lines in the file but correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Test it with fake data. I'm pretty sure it wouldn't

Comment: Also, what if number is two digit or more? 'line[0]' will take first character not entire number.

Answer (score 0):

- Read line
- Split it on basis of comma
- Append first element to temp list.

Once complete reading of file is done,

- To get maximum number, just use `max` function on temp list.
- Since file is read line by line sequentially and appending number from line to temp list, to get line number on which maximum number is present, just find the index of max number in temp list and increment it by one since list index starts with zero.

**P.S :** Check last three print statements

**Code:**

```
num_list = []
with open('master.csv','r')as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        num_list.append(int((line.split(','))[0]))

print num_list
print "Max number is -" ,max(num_list)
print "Line number is - ", (num_list.index(max(num_list)))+1
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
[1, 2, 3]
Max number is - 3
Line number is -  3

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Comment: It works and thank you but I still have a question. How can I get the line the biggest number is on? And how does line 4 of your code work? Because you only split it, how does it find the largest number?

Comment: On line 4, I am not getting max number. On line 4, as I mention in answer, I am just splitting line on basis of comma and appending first element to temp list.

Comment: Once I have done with lines, then I am using max function to get maximum number from list. ---- max(num_list)

Comment: Since I am reading file line by line and appending number from line to list, to get line number on which maximum number is present, I am just finding the index of max number in list and incrementing it by one since list index starts with zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd go about doing it.

```
max_num = 0
with open('file.txt', 'r') as data: # use the with context so that the file closes gracefully
  for line in data.readlines(): # read the lines as a generator to be nice to my memory
    try:
      val = int(line.split(",")[0])
    except ValueError: # just incase the text file is not formatted like your example
      val = 0
    if val > max_num: # logic
      max_num = val

print max_num #result
```

Answer (score 0):

You need loop over each line in file, parse each line and find the largest number.

I do not quite understand how the numbers are stored in your file. Just assuming that in each line, the first field are numeric and separate with others (non-numeric) by `','`. And I assume all numbers are integer.

```
ln = 0
maxln = 0
maxn = 0
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    line = f.next()
    if line:
       ln = 1
       maxln = 1
       maxn = int(line.split(",")[0].strip())
    else:
       raise Exception('Empty content')
    for line in f:
        ln += 1
        cur = int(line.split(",")[0].strip())
        if cur > maxn:
            maxn = cur
            maxln = ln
```

ln is used to record current line number, maxn is used to record current maximum number, and maxln is used to record current maximum number location.

One thing you need to do is fetch the first line to initialize these variables.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers give you the line of the max number so I'll post some quick code and refine later

```
max_num = 0
line_count = 0
with open('file.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        number = int(line.split(',')[0])
        if number > max_num:
             max_num = number
             line_num = line_count
        line_count += 1
print (max_num)
print (line_num)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The line is not correct but I guess I can fix that. I still am wondering what your 5th line exactly does. It splits the line at ',' but how does it get the highest number?

Comment: @SamVruggink Can you tell me what's not correct? In your sample code, the numbers appear on the left of the "," so I'm just taking that value and trying to record the maximum

Comment: @SamVruggink It gets the maximum by comparing to a value stored in `max_num`. If the value of `number` exceeds `max_num` then `max_num` will take the value of `number` and `line_num` will record the line on which this occured

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through the file and keep track of the highest number you've seen and the line you found it on. Just replace this with the new number and new line number when you see a bigger one.

```
b = open('file.txt', 'r')
max = -1
lineNum = -1
line = b.readline()
index = 0
while(line):
    index+=1
    newNum = line[0]
    if(newNum>max):
        max = newNum
        lineNum = index
    line = b.readline()
print lineNum,max,index
```

max is your highest number, lineNum is where it was, and index is the number of lines in the file

Comment: This isn't valid Python. Did you test it?

Comment: I forgot the readline in the while statement. Other than that, it works for Python2.7, and it's easy enough to convert over to Python3 if you want.